# Display current logged in user's profile

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on code for student registration. I finished coding for my log in.

What I'm having a problem with is showing the user's profile: student `fname`, `lname`, `program`, `gender` and `year` level in textboxes. I'm using MySQL as my back end.

My code is like this:

```
<?php 

// connects to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");

$query = 'SELECT fname, lname, program, gender, year FROM students WHERE fname =     '.$_SESSION['myusername'];
$mysqli->query($query);


echo "<div align=\"center\">";
echo "<br />Your <b><i>Profile</i></b> is as follows:<br />";
echo "<b>First name:</b> ". $_POST['fname'];
echo "<br /><b>Last name:</b> ".$_POST['lname'];
echo "<br /><b>Program:</b> ".$_POST['program'];
echo "<br /><b>Year:</b> ".$_POST['year'];
echo "<br /><b>Gender:</b> ".$_POST['gender'];
echo "</div>";
?>
```

This is my code for [mainstudent.php](http://pastebin.com/jEuXtArd) and [checklogin.php](http://pastebin.com/GH2UbGpJ).

Comment: First, you need to start the session by calling `session_start()` before PHP will put anything in `$_SESSION` for you. Beyond that, your query won't run because there are no quotes around the username. You then never read the result of the query and use it in your output. There's too much missing to really "answer" this; you haven't written the code yet.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the session_start() function, what Im missing is to display each fields on textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php 
session_start();

// connects to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");

$query = "SELECT fname, lname, program, gender, year FROM students WHERE fname = '".$_SESSION['myusername']."'";
if($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<div align=\"center\">";
        echo "<br />Your <b><i>Profile</i></b> is as follows:<br />";
        echo "<b>First name:</b> ". $row['fname'];
        echo "<br /><b>Last name:</b> ".$row['lname'];
        echo "<br /><b>Program:</b> ".$row['program'];
        echo "<br /><b>Year:</b> ".$row['year'];
        echo "<br /><b>Gender:</b> ".$row['gender'];
        echo "</div>"   
    }
    $result->free();
}
else
{
    echo "No results found";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi tried your code above, but it gives me an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\say\students\profilestudent.php on line 8

Comment: missed a quote in my query. Updated answer. try now.

Comment: Hi, where the opening bracket here? $query = "SELECT fname, lname, program, gender, year FROM students WHERE fname = '".$_SESSION['myusername']."'");

Comment: grrr...seems its sleeping time for me!!! removed that from answer. Just delete the bracket from the string.

Comment: Okay I already did, but I think this line $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); is giving me some hard time.

Comment: Yup, it's giving me this: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: that is because your query did not give you any results..so `$results` is empty and you cannot call `fetch_assoc` on it. print the query and run it against the database and see if you get any results

Comment: When I print the query it gives me results. I'm wondering why it's not giving me results on textboxes

Comment: Ok, I have added additional message in the code to check if results are being fetched. If you run it and you get `No results found` then could be problem with how you connect. You need to pass correct server, username, password and database name to `new mysqli()` function

Comment: I think it could be the the $_SESSION that's giving me problem, when I am in the mainstudent.php and click on the profile tab, it just gives me no results found.

Comment: oh ok, in that case add `session_start()` as the first line of the php file - have updated answer to reflect it

Comment: Thanks for your patience, uhm I already did put session_start() function, but it's just the same.

Comment: You have session_start() in both pages? Can you do an `echo $query` and paste the query?

Comment: Yes I have in both pages. when i added this echo $query it gives: SELECT fname, lname, program, gender, year FROM students WHERE fname = 'Say' note that it does not give the fields but instead the fieldname.

Comment: I really think the value you have in session is wrong..I dont think there is a firstname called 'Say' in your database. You might want to check what value you have stored inside $_SESSION['myusername']

Comment: Yes there is a fname Say, for I myself added that. When I tried to query it in mysql it's showing me results. On mainstudent.php, it welcomes the user this is the line I used: Welcome " .$_SESSION['myusername']. "!, Today is: " .date("Y/m/d")."</div><br />";

Comment: You need to pass correct server, username, password and database name to new mysqli() function

Comment: Yes, the database name is missing! it's now resolved @Raidenance.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

please add your password in session as well

Comment: I leave it blank for a moment

Comment: hey u can use fetch_Query instead fetch_assoc

Comment: @SandeepTiwari: What is the rationale behind adding password into session? Sensitive data such as password should **never** be stored in session. Secondly, I do not think mysqli has a fetch_Query function..